# difference between timezone in ssh and in php?

Tags: timezone

why i have difference  between timezone in ssh and php

```
$ TZ=Africa/Khartoum date
```

print : 
Mon Apr 30 13:40:41 CAT 2018

but in php

```
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Khartoum');
echo date('D M d Y H:i:s');
```

print :
Mon Apr 30 14:40:41 CAT 2018

so how can i fix this , and i know in ssh time is correct time , but in php its not correct ?

Comment: I'd start by setting the timezone in your php.ini instead of using the PHP function...

Comment: PHP is probably executed as web-browser user not the owner of the files (so not as the ssh user). Different user, different locale and timezone. `phpinfo()` could help you.

Comment: thx all , but i need to show with two location  time in php , and wana show correct time as ssh , so is there any way to get this time in ssh to php